# HttpGet getting text with unwanted characters

Tags: java, android, http-get

I have this in my MainActivity.java file:

```
public static void getLatestVersion() {
        try {
            String myUri = "http://www.stonequest.de/version.php";
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(myUri);

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get);

            String Latest = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            System.out.println(Latest);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

It gets the text, but it also adds some special characters at the beginning of the text.

This is what I get:

> ï»¿0.1.572

I wish to retrieve the version without any characters as shown by going to the endpoint http://www.stonequest.de/version.php

> 0.1.572

So how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querying this URL with Firefox, I can see the same characters in the response body (with Firebug). You should mention the characterset in the toString() method, and use the same as on the server side. Preferably set both to "UTF-8".

Comment: yeah ... server do not returns charset(in a header) ... forcing utf-8 would do the thing ... "the thing" before the string looks like a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

Comment: I can't test right now but I would go with `EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8")`

Comment: @dotvav I know, I found out by myself :)